# Linq/Lambda complex query to get result by two different fields

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

Hi I have table that has following information

```
id    StoretId  itemId  Mon   Tue   Wed  
1       1         20     33   10     5   
2       1         21     1     0     3 
3       1         20     3     2     1
4       2         21     2     1     1
5       2         20     1      1    1
6       2         21     4      4    5
```

What I am trying to do is to get result by each storeId and total of items for each day by itemId, so it looks like this.

```
StoreId 1
    itemId     Mon   Tue   Wed
      20        36    12    6
      21        1      0    3
StoreId 2
     itemId    Mon  Tue Wed
      20        1    1   1
      21        6    5   6
```

I have done so far if user inputs list of stores to get results for i.e

```
  storelist= [{storeId :1}, {storeId: 2}, {storeId: 3}]



var results= DbContext.Set<stores>()
             .Where(x=> storelist.Contains(x.storeId)
             .Select(y=> new 
                      {
                          storeId=y.storeId,
                           itemsdetails= DbContext.Set<maintable>()
                                        .Select(m=> new 
                                              {
                                                itemId=m.itemId.Distinct(),
                                                Mon=m.Mon.Sum(),
                                                Tue=m.Tue.Sum(),
                                                Wed=m.Wed.Sum()
                                              }
                       }
```

Query conceptually looks fine but it breaks and doesn't give result. Please let me know how to fix it to get the desired output. 
Thanks

Comment: I think you need to use groupby instead of Distinct. Try to re-write the query with groupby. Hope It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

must be grouped by both  StoreID and ItemID 
and select sum of other values as result:

var result = from item in list

```
                      group item by new  

                     {  

                          item.StoreID,  

                          item.ItemID  

                      } into groupList  

                      select new  

                       {  

                          StoreID = groupList.Key.StoreID,  

                          ItemID = groupList.Key.ItemID,  

                          mon = groupList.Sum(i => i.mon),  

                          tue = groupList.Sum(i => i.tue),  

                          wed = groupList.Sum(i => i.wed)  

                     };
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `GroupBy` to group by store and then select the columns by the sum of the group

```
var result = list.GroupBy(o => o.StoreId)
    .Select((o, i) => new
    {
        ID = o.ElementAt(i).ID,
        StoreId = o.Key,
        Mon = o.Sum(x => x.Mon),
        Tue = o.Sum(x => x.Tue),
        Wed = o.Sum(x => x.Wed),
    }).ToList();
```